# Рисовать на фото пальцем. (React Native)

Tags: javascript, canvas, reactjs, react-native

Всем привет.
Делаю приложение на React Native для Android.
Нужно сделать так, чтобы при создании фото можно было рисовать на нем пальцем. Проблема с прорисовкой.
Как это сделать? Что можно использовать? Никогда этим не занимался.

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен что можно будет рисовать прям на картинке. Но можно используя эту библиотеку [react-native-sketch-canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@terrylinla/react-native-sketch-canvas) разместить полотно рисования поверх картинки, и рисовать то что вам нужно. У вас будет отдельно оригинальная картинка и отдельно рисунок на ней.